# Cucumber-Jvm produces empty Json file when any of the test Fails

Tags: json, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-jvm

I have about 50 feature files running on Jenkin Server and it produces .JSON file  which will be fed into Cucumber Pie chart generator.

Jenkin produces file when All Tests Succeeds, and produces Pie chart as well

When any of the Test Step fails , It generates file with zero size (empty file)

My project is setup using surefire plug in...I dont know if that matters...

Thanks

Comment: Show your cucumber test runner?

Comment: Resolved :                                                         // exit with 1 if there were failure or errors during run
 //System.exit(stats.hadErrors() || stats.hadFailures() ? 1 : 0);
 System.exit(0);

Answer (score 0):

The Way Cucumber exits.....

//System.exit(stats.hadErrors() || stats.hadFailures() ? 1 : 0);

System.exit(0);

Comment: Hello @manish, can you please elaborate:
- is this a cucumber patch?
- which java class is this command located in?
- are the html reports generated now by cucumber?